# header border coming in underneath image also. (css3)

Tags: html, css

```css
.top {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  border: orange 25px outset;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.demo-2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.demo-2 p,
.demo-2 h2 {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  left: -20px;
  top: 20px;
  position: relative
}
.demo-2 p {
  font-family: 'American captain';
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 0
}
.demo-2 h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'American captain'
}
.effect img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: -12px 0;
  -webkit-transition: bottom .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: bottom .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: bottom .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: bottom .3s ease-in-out
}
.effect img.top:hover {
  bottom: -96px;
  padding-top: 100px
}
h2.zero,
p.zero {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/qmybkmtqtg88gzoyltt1.jpg" alt="A Sam Hawkz Production" style="width:100%;height: 450px;">
</div>

<ul class="demo-2 effect">
  <li>
    <h2 class="zero">This is a cool title!</h2>
    <p class="zero">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img class="top" src="http://casuallyhardcore.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/hardcore-gamer.jpg" alt="" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

The 'top' class is for the first image in which i want the border and the 'demo-2' class is for the second image in which the border is coming but i don't want that. I saw the code a lot of times but there is no border attribute in any of the demo-2 class. [image: This is the real image of the problem.]. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

you are using same class `.top` for `div`  and `img` tag.

```
.top {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  border: orange 25px outset;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

change to

```
.top {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

div.top {
   border: orange 25px outset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `class="top"` for second image as shown bellow

```
 <pre>
 <li>
    <img src="http://casuallyhardcore.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/hardcore-gamer.jpg" alt="" />
  </li>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the top class from second image and define a new class for it.

```html
<div class="top">
  <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/qmybkmtqtg88gzoyltt1.jpg" alt="A Sam Hawkz Production" style="width:100%;height: 450px;">
</div>

<ul class="demo-2 effect">
  <li>
    <h2 class="zero">This is a cool title!</h2>
    <p class="zero">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://casuallyhardcore.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/hardcore-gamer.jpg" alt="" />
  </li>
</ul>
```